# SP Online rest api: how to get the "author byline field"?

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, sharepoint-fields, sharepoint-news

This gets the name in the "created by" field fine, but for news posts I need the "author byline" field:

```
https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?$select=Title,FileRef,CanvasContent1,Videourl,BannerImageUrl,Author/Title&$expand=Author&$filter=ID eq '193'
```

The internal field name is "_AuthorByline" but the response is that doesn't exist. Does the field have to be a managed property for the api call to work?

I should add that in a search rest api, "Author" returns the "AuthorByline" field, if populated, "created by" if not..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this out-the syntax to get authorbyline for a specific page is:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Site Pages')/items?$select=OData__AuthorByline/Title&$expand=OData__AuthorByline&$filter=ID eq '<pageid>'
```

Thanks to [user92888](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/92888/user92888) for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can get to the field using: `OData__AuthorBylineId`
If you dive into `items(id)/properties` - you will be able to get the AuthorByline items.

This is a person-field allowing multiple persons.

Also in Flow the Byline field shows on an item.